# Resetting a password

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to reset a password when `password_reset_token` is received in the controller. But it's becoming a long `if` `else` ladder of many conditions. Can it be reduced in a better way?

```
def set_new_password
    if params[:password_reset_token].present?
      @user = User.find_by(password_reset_token: params[:password_reset_token])
      if @user.present?
        if params[:password] != params[:password_confirmation]
          render json: {errors: ["Your password confirmation doesn't match"]}, status: :unprocessable_entity
        elsif @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
          render json: {errors: ["Your password reset expired. Please require a new password reset from the app."]}, status: :unprocessable_entity
        elsif @user.update(user_params)
          @user.update(password_reset_token: nil, password_reset_sent_at: nil)
          render :json => {:success => true}
        end
      else
         render json: {errors: ["Password reset not found. Please request a new password reset!"]}, status: 404
      end
    else
      render json: {errors: ["Password reset not found. Please request a new password reset!"]}, status: 404
    end
  end
```

Comment: The "standard" solution to this would be Guard Clauses...

Answer (score 1):

Below is refactoring code you can use:

```
def set_new_password
  @user = User.find_by(password_reset_token: params[:password_reset_token]) if params[:password_reset_token].present?

  unless user
    render json: {
       errors: ["Password reset not found. Please request a new password reset!"]
    }, status: 404 and return
  end

  if params[:password] != params[:password_confirmation]
    render json: { errors: ["Your password confirmation doesn't match"] }, status: :unprocessable_entity

  elsif @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
    render json: {
      errors: ["Your password reset expired. Please require a new password reset from the app."]
    }, status: :unprocessable_entity

  else
    updated_params = user_params.merge(password_reset_token: nil, password_reset_sent_at: nil)

    @user.update(updated_params) ?
      render :json => {:success => true} :
      render :json => {:success => false}
  end
end
```

I also suggest to move validation password confirmation match with password to model using standard ActiveRecord validation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#confirmation

Answer (score 0):

```
def set_new_password
  # This will return nil if there is no reset_token param so there is no need for that extra check
  @user = User.find_by(password_reset_token: params[:password_reset_token])

  # I prefer to fail early when possible
  unless @user.present?
    render json: {errors: ["Password reset not found. Please request a new password reset!"]}, status: 404
  end

  if params[:password] != params[:password_confirmation]
    render json: {errors: ["Your password confirmation doesn't match"]}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  elsif @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
    render json: {errors: ["Your password reset expired. Please require a new password reset from the app."]}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  elsif @user.update(user_params)
    @user.update(password_reset_token: nil, password_reset_sent_at: nil)
    render :json => {:success => true}
  end
end
```

This is a small refactoring for the given code. I prefer to guard against fails as soon as I can and [fail early](https://blog.codinghorror.com/fail-early-fail-often/).
Another improvement you could do is to extract your API responses, for example respond("Password reset not found.", 404), but you will need to understand [controller returns](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/07/4-ways-to-early-return-from-a-rails-controller/).

In this case I would create a PasswordSetterService class, and do something like this:

```
def set_new_password
  service = PasswordSetterService.new(@user, params)
  service.validate

  if service.errors?
    render json: service.error
  else
    render json: { success: true }
  end
end

class PasswordSetterService
  attr_accessor :error

  def initialize(user, params)
    @user = user
    @params = params
  end

  def validate
    @user = User.find_by(password_reset_token: @params[:password_reset_token])

    message = "Password reset not found. Please request a new password reset!"

    unless @user.present?
      @error = message
      return
    end

    # Other validations
  end
end
```

But do keep in mind that this is my personal opinion.